# Django Form with Data on the beginning

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to Form start With some Data set. When i Do this, Gives me an error (**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'). Why?

```
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = UcitelZmenaForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            form = UcitelZmenaForm(request.POST)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/hlavni_stranka/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = UcitelZmenaForm(user=request.user) # An unbound form

class Clovek(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    mesto=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)



class Ucitel(Clovek): #pridat pote classu tridniho ucitele
    predmety=models.ManyToManyField(Predmety) #manyToManyField

class UcitelZmenaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ucitel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
form = UcitelZmenaForm(user=request.user)
```

to

```
form = UcitelZmenaForm(initial={'user': request.user})
```

See also: ["Dynamic initial values"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) in Django Forms documentation.